# Which method measures the degree of disagreement in online comments?

Tags: computational-linguistics, discourse-analysis

I am researching Fake News as a topic at my university. Right now, I am searching for some literature in which a method for measuring the degree of disagreement in an online comment setting (Facebook, Twitter, Forums, ...) is presented. However, I can't seem to provide Google some key words to find a method for measuring the degree of disagreement between comments. Are there any natural language analysis methods or libraries out there which provide one of these methods?

Comment: Good luck. Afaik, lots of people are working on this full time, and nobody knows any algorithm for anything as subtle as disagreement, let alone degree of disagreement. It's easy to search for words, but text structures are much less simple to extract, and they often don't indicate attitudes.